# Change UI text color in VS Code

Tags: colors, visual-studio-code

I am using theme in vs code called "Monokai Pro".
Is there any way to change the color of the UI of vs code to chosen color ?
Colors in some text (in the attached image) like "Cut", "Copy", "Copy As", ... can be changed ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this [article](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-colors) and edit settings.json file in vscode directory